# Swift_TransportException Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username

Tags: php, apache, smtp, cpanel, swiftmailer

Hey awesome programmers!

Glad to see you all :)

This is my site...     `http://www.newdelhifreeads.com`
I use `cpanel`.

This type of question has been asked but mine is a little different.

Whenever anyone tries to register on my site or try to post a free ad, the following error message results:

```
Swift_Transport Exception

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@newdelhifreeads.com" using 2 possible authenticators

/home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/Core/extensions/vendors/mail/vendors/swiftMailer/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php(179)

167       foreach ($this->_getAuthenticatorsForAgent() as $authenticator)
168       {
169         if (in_array(strtolower($authenticator->getAuthKeyword()),
170           array_map('strtolower', $this->_esmtpParams)))
171         {
172           $count++;
173           if ($authenticator->authenticate($agent, $this->_username, $this->_password))
174           {
175             return;
176           }
177         }
178       }
179       throw new Swift_TransportException(
180         'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "' .
181         $this->_username . '" using ' . $count . ' possible authenticators'
182         );
183     }
184   }
185   
186   /**
187    * Not used.
188    */
189   public function getMailParams()
190   {
191     return array();
Stack Trace
#0  
–  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/Core/extensions/vendors/mail/vendors/swiftMailer/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(252): Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(Swift_SmtpTransport)
247 
248     $this->_capabilities = $this->_getCapabilities($response);
249     $this->_setHandlerParams();
250     foreach ($this->_getActiveHandlers() as $handler)
251     {
252       $handler->afterEhlo($this);
253     }
254   }
255   
256   /** Overridden to add Extension support */
257   protected function _doMailFromCommand($address)
#1  
–  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/Core/extensions/vendors/mail/vendors/swiftMailer/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(108): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand()
103       catch (Swift_TransportException $e)
104       {
105         $this->_throwException($e);
106       }
107       $this->_readGreeting();
108       $this->_doHeloCommand();
109       
110       if ($evt)
111       {
112         $this->_eventDispatcher->dispatchEvent($evt, 'transportStarted');
113       }
#2  
–  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/Core/extensions/vendors/mail/vendors/swiftMailer/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(74): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
69   {
70     $failedRecipients = (array) $failedRecipients;
71     
72     if (!$this->_transport->isStarted())
73     {
74       $this->_transport->start();
75     }
76     
77     return $this->_transport->send($message, $failedRecipients);
78   }
79   
#3  
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/Core/extensions/vendors/mail/YiiMail.php(133): Swift_Mailer->send(Swift_Message, array())
#4  
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/User/services/UserService.php(311): YiiMail->send(YiiMailMessage)
#5  
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/Core/extensions/base/FSM.php(106): UserService->registerInFrontEnd(array("User" => array("email" => "tips4youawesome@gmail.com", "first_name" => "Naveen", "last_name" => "Gift", "verifyCode" => "uumohu"), "btnRegister" => "Register"))
#6  
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/modules/Core/extensions/base/FSM.php(133): FSM::_run("User.User.registerInFrontEnd", array("User" => array("email" => "tips4youawesome@gmail.com", "first_name" => "Naveen", "last_name" => "Gift", "verifyCode" => "uumohu"), "btnRegister" => "Register"), false)
#7  
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/protected/controllers/SiteController.php(139): FSM::run("User.User.registerInFrontEnd", array("User" => array("email" => "tips4youawesome@gmail.com", "first_name" => "Naveen", "last_name" => "Gift", "verifyCode" => "uumohu"), "btnRegister" => "Register"))
#8  
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/yii-1.1.7.r3135/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(50): SiteController->actionRegister()
#9  
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/yii-1.1.7.r3135/framework/web/CController.php(300): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array())
#10 
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/yii-1.1.7.r3135/framework/web/CController.php(278): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
#11 
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/yii-1.1.7.r3135/framework/web/CController.php(257): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array())
#12 
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/yii-1.1.7.r3135/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(328): CController->run("register")
#13 
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/yii-1.1.7.r3135/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(121): CWebApplication->runController("site/register")
#14 
+  /home/newdelhi/public_html/yii-1.1.7.r3135/framework/base/CApplication.php(155): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#15 
+  /home/`newdelhi`/public_html/`index.php`(42): `CApplication`->run()
```

Could anyone please help me out with this?

It would be a great help!
Thanks.......... ;)

Comment: Have you configured your SMTP settings?

Comment: Hello Rob W.

I am perfectly able to send/receive emails from my website email address.

But whenever anyone tries to register on my site or try to post a free ad, the above error message results.

Comment: Assuming you're using Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html

Comment: Hello again Rob sir.
I went through the above reference but it wasn't of much help!
My site is created using this site : http://www.titanclassifieds.com/

And I use cpanel Accelerated 2 version as in this image:
http://techark.com/images/cpanel_accelerated.jpg

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

This might be old but somebody might get help through this. I too faced the same problem and received a mail on my gmail account stating that someone is trying to hack your account through an email client or a different site.
THen I searched and found that doing below would resolve this issue.

Go to https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha‎
and unlock your account for access through other media/sites.

UPDATE : 2015

Also, you can try this, Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps
At the bottom, towards right there is an option "Allow less secure apps". If it is "OFF", turn it on by sliding the button.